# Illegal quoting in line 1 (CSV::MalformedCSVError) after rewinding file with encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

When I read data from valid CSV file with correct encoding specified and use rewind function, then reading fails (error below is produced). Same file works fine without the rewind.

This only happens when using CSV.new() with File.new() with encoding specified. It does not happen when using CSV.read() or CSV.new() from String object or from file where encoding is not specified (needed). It seems like during CSV.rewind (which calls IO.rewind) the file encoding information gets lost.
Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?
I avoided the issue by using CSV.read, but then the whole file goes to memory and I don't want that.

test.rb:

```rb
require 'csv'
csvdata = CSV.new(
  File.new('test.csv', 'rb:BOM|UTF-8'),
  :col_sep => ';', 
  :quote_char => '"',
  :headers => true)
csvdata.rewind
csvdata.each do |r| 
  puts r.inspect
end
```

test.csv:

```
"Col 1";"Col 2";"Col 3"
"ROW1";"";""
"ROW2";"";""
"ROW3";"";""
```

Without rewind, everything goes OK. With rewind, following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9: from test.rb:9:in `<main>'
    8: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
    7: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
    6: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:303:in `parse'
    5: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:779:in `parse_quotable_loose'
    4: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
    3: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
    2: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:31:in `block in each_line'
    1: from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:818:in `block in parse_quotable_loose'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:879:in `parse_quotable_robust': Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: Not sure what's causing the error but ... why do you want to `rewind` the file?

Comment: It seems your `File.new` code is not valid ruby code

Comment: Your username dredges up memories of [Turbo Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal).